# For Loop with Multiplication Implementer Complexity

Tags: java, runtime, complexity-theory

```
for(int i=1; i<n; i=2*i)
// simple addition performed here...
```

I understand O(n) runtime single for loops and O(n^2) nested for loops but is the runtime on this loop also n log n since the multiplication?

Thank you,

Comment: It is quite likely the JVM will optimise this to `i+i` or `i << 1` both of which are more efficient.  if `n` is greater than 2^30, this will loop forever. ;)

Answer (score 5):

No, you're right that there's multiplication going on here but it serves to *reduce* the added running time, not to *increase* it.

You have to look at how quick the loop finishes based on the input value `n`. For `n = 128`, you'll get `i = 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128`. If you double `n`, that doesn't double time as it would for O(n) and it certainly doesn't multiply it by 4 as it would for O(n<sup>2</sup>). It simply adds one more iteration to the loop.

That's what's known as an O(log N) time complexity. The running time rises with the *logarithm* of the input value and it's commonly seen in thing like balanced binary tree searches where you can remove half of the remaining search space with each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

As @paxdiablo states, this is a loop of O(log n)

O(n log n) would be

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) 
   for(int j=i;j>0;j/=2)
```

When is a nested loop of O(n) and O(log n)